# CMS cap has more vega exposure than CMS floor for same strike

Tags: options, volatility, vega, cms

When I priced a 10y expiry single look CMS30 **ATMF CAP**, I noticed that the vega exposure is higher than that of the same 10y expiry single look CMS30 **ATMF FLOOR**. Why is that?

I have a suspicion that it is due to the Vol of Vol exposure of the CMS index where in a cap you are long vol in the cap and long VoV on the CMS index while in a floor you are long vol in the floor but short VoV on the CMS index.

Is that correct/is there a way to formalize this?

Thanks!